# Singularities of power series with coefficients over $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, power-series, singularity-theory

Given power series with coefficients over $\mathbb{N}$, how to find it's singularity and the order of singularities, if it is with natural boundary, how to find it's order of singularities, and compare their orders?

For example, $$S(x)=\sum_{i= 1}^{\infty}\frac{x^i}{(1-x)(1-x^2)\dots(1-x^i)}$$

it is able to be expanded further to a power series with coefficients over $\mathbb{N}$, which has a natural boundary. Then how to find and  compare their orders of singularities

Comment: What do you want to know on this natural boundary on $|z| = 1$ (the only one singularity of your function), the growth rate of $\sup_{|z| < 1-\epsilon} |S(z)|$ ?. Also why not mention this comes from a theta function ?

Comment: @reuns, really? are you serious? could you check what natural boundary means? I cannot believe what you say.

Comment: What do you mean **exactly**